# Specifying different gems with the same name in different blocks in a Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

I'm working on moving an application from ruby 1.8.7 to jRuby 1.6.7. We have some local dependencies of which we have two versions: one for ruby and one for jruby.

My gemfile looks this:

```
platforms :jruby do
  gem "service_client", :require => 'service_client', :path => '../service_client_jruby'
end

platforms :mri do
  gem "service_client", :require => 'service_client', :path => '../service_client'
end
```

When running bundle install I get the following error:

You cannot specify the same gem twice coming from different sources. You specified that service_client (~> 0.5.16) should come from source at ../service_client_jruby and source at ../service_client

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Looks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338154/187009) like you need to use ruby for the control sequence rather than the bundler dsl. You could try checking `RUBY_VERSION` or `system("ruby -v")`. Sorry I can't be more specific but I've not got time to install jruby just to check!