# How to create a fake gem which can appear in gem list

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How can I make a gem appear in gem list without actually doing a gem install?

I did try to look at the GemRunner code but didn't get it.

Comment: I want it to appear in my local gems. So locally if i do a 'gem list', it should show up

Comment: Can you please tell why you need this facility?  Are you writing some kind of test around `gem list` output?

Comment: This is for my own purpose. So my friend is writing a code which depends on the list of gems installed by doing a 'gem list', I want to see how can I fake the returned list.

Comment: @AnkushGanatra Do you run the `gem list` from command line or Ruby program?

Comment: Through command line

Comment: @AnkushGanatra obviously `gem list` would be in command line :P

Answer (score 1):

The file `<rub-install-dir>/bin/gem`is a Ruby script that executes gem commands. When using command line it uses `Gem::ConsoleUI` defined in [`user_interaction.rb`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/4a778c9c2489745e37bcc2d0a8f12c601a9c517f/lib/rubygems/user_interaction.rb). Hence, gem commands will typically dump the output of commands to console.

For your tests, you may want to use `Gem::MockGemUi` which lets you collect output of gem list command to a string.

Here is a sample Ruby program to demonstrate that.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/commands/list_command'
require 'rubygems/mock_gem_ui'

list_command = Gem::Commands::ListCommand.new
p list_command.ui
list_command.ui = Gem::MockGemUi.new
list_command.execute

list_command.ui.outs << "fake_gem (2.1.0)"
puts list_command.ui.output
```

Output will be something like this:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.5, 4.2.4)
actionpack (4.2.5, 4.2.4)
...
warden (1.2.3)
web-console (2.2.1)
fake_gem (2.1.0)
```

The last line is a fake gem.

More information can be found by studying how RubyGems have written its [tests](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/test/rubygems/test_gem_commands_query_command.rb).

It may not be a good idea to modify `bin/gem` file to have custom output though, it will be better to use `Gem::Commands::*` in your test class

Comment: Thanks @WandMaker, but i see that this isn't persistent, some insight on how to make that? So like, if anytime i do a gem list, it should show that fake gem.

Comment: That may not be possible

Comment: Ok. I will up-vote this since It did help me to some extent. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

**1:** `gem 'My_own_gem', path: '<path-for-directory>'`

**2:** Run `bundle install`

```
group :development do
  gem 'awesome', :path => "~/code/awesome"
end
```

For More Info check-out [how-can-bundler-gemfile-be-configured-to-use-different-gem-sources-during-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337773/how-can-bundler-gemfile-be-configured-to-use-different-gem-sources-during-develo)

Hope this help you !!!

Comment: Will this help to create a fake gem as OP is asking?

Comment: @vinay, thanks for quick response, but its not related to what I am looking for.

Comment: Yes !!! Indeed because i had added this line in my gemfile _gem 'bing-ads-api', :path => "~/bing-ads-api"_  .And after _bundle install_ .It shows  _Using bing-ads-api 0.3 from source at ~/bing-ads-api_ in bundle log file.And further as @Ankush is asking about to _How to create a fake gem which can appear in gem list_. I think it is an answer But Still make me correct if I'm missing something .

Comment: @vinay. I want a gem to appear in the 'gem list' without actually creating one.